# How to use multiple CustomView in single xml?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I am trying to use two custom tag in single xml file, but either of one is calling I want to show both simultaneously.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <com.example.android.animations.SecondballView
        android:id="@+id/second_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

         />

    <com.example.android.animations.AnimatedView
        android:id="@+id/anim_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

If anyone want any further code or snippet let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your first view is set to match_parent, so it pushes the second out of the screen. Set it to wrap_content or layout_height="0dp" and layout_weight="1" instead.

Comment: Then the height of your first view is probably too big, so the second doesn't fit. In that case the only solution is to wrap the LinearLayout in a ScrollView -- or split everything in two Activities/Fragments. If that's not the problem, you're not providing enough information about what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: In 10 inch tablet I want to make multiple balls bounce randomly at same time. For that I need custom view.